Alternatives for heredocs in bashscripts? External templating?
I currently use many heredocs in bash scripts.
These heredocs contain bash variables, e.g. ${MY_VAR}, which are substituted as the script executes and the heredoc is read.
Some of these heredocs have grown to hundreds of lines long, and so I would like to put these in their own files.
Unfortunately this breaks the variable substitution.  I could add boilerplate to each file, turning each file into its own bash script (containing their own heredoc, which uses environment variables).  This feels like pointless complexity.
Is there a way of making bash perform variable substitution on an external file as it is read in?

Take a look at envsubst command.

@Philippe Thanks for the suggestion.  I've read that envsubst requires me to export all the needed variables, and that it doesn't handle escaped variables which need to remain variables.  e.g. \${foo}  Have I understood correctly?

You don't have to use explicitly export. Try MY_VAR=$MY_VAR envsubst '${MY_VAR}' <  heredoc.txt. For the escaping, you can try '$MY_VAR' to differentiate $MY_VAR from ${MY_VAR}

Always include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input, expected output and your code attempt to solve your problem in every question. See [ask].

You could use php, erb, or some templating lib like mustache

So you have in your template file both $foo and \$foo, and only the former needs to be substituted? In this case, I would devote a namespace of the variables to be substituted, i.e. name all those which undergo substitution something like sub_foo, and do a sub_foo=$foo envsubst ..... Note also that you can tell envsubst, which variables it should substitute.

Assuming you fully trust these files, one option is to write a function that reads the file and adds the boilerplate that you mention, and then use the source built-in with process substitution to execute the result inside the main script's execution environment.
That is, something like this:
function boilerplatify() {
  local varname="$1"
  local filepath="$2"
  echo "$varname=<<EOF"
  cat -- "$filepath"
  echo EOF
}

source <(boilerplatify my_var /path/to/template)

